# switch-case does not work properly

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

i the below posted code, when I leave the field `ip` blank/empty and give values to the other fields, the `toast` always gives message the `KATimer is invalid or missing`.

i expected to see a `toast` showing with a message indicating the empty field,but the below code, if any field is empty, it always says `KATimer is invalid or empty`.

why that is happeneing, i am missing something

**Code:**

**btnStubView_Connect**:

```
btnStubView_Connect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (isValidMQTTConfigs(etStubView_ip) && 
                    isValidMQTTConfigs(etStubView_port) && 
                    isValidMQTTConfigs(etStubView_ClientID) &&
                    isValidMQTTConfigs(etStubView_KATimer)) {

                Log.d(TAG, "@btnStubView_ConnectListener(): all entries are valid");
                setCSession(cbStubView_CS.isChecked()); // set the current state of the cleanSession checkBox.
                addToContentValues();
                Log.d(TAG, "@btnStubView_ConnectListener(): all entries added toContentValues");

            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "@btnStubView_ConnectListener(): one or more entry(s) is invalid or left blank.");
            }
        }
    });
```

**isValidMQTTConfigs**:

```
protected boolean isValidMQTTConfigs(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean valid = false;
    String viewName = "";

    switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.etSubView_ip:
        viewName = "IP";
        if (isDuly( ((EditText) view).getText().toString())) {
            this.setIP(((EditText) view).getText().toString());
            return valid = true;
        }

    case R.id.etSubView_port:
        viewName = "Port";
        if (isDuly( ((EditText) view).getText().toString())) {
            this.setPort(((EditText) view).getText().toString());
            return valid = true;
        }

    case R.id.etSubView_clientID:
        viewName = "clientID";
        if (isDuly( ((EditText) view).getText().toString())) {
            this.setClienID(((EditText) view).getText().toString());
            return valid = true;
        }

    case R.id.etSubView_KATimer:
        viewName = "KAtimer";
        if (isDuly( ((EditText) view).getText().toString())) {
            this.setKATimer(((EditText) view).getText().toString());
            return valid = true;
        }
    }

    Log.w(TAG, "@checkMQTTConfigs(): " + viewName + " is invalid or missing");
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), viewName + " is invalid or missing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return valid;
}
```

**isDuly**:

```
private boolean isDuly(String text) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (text.trim().equals("")) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: not a good question.use break

Comment: switch-case **does work properly**... if you know how to use it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing several break statements.

```
Switch(X){
case 1: doOne();
case 2: doTwo();
case 3: doThree();
}
```

the waterfall flow makes sure that if X is 2, both doTwo and doThree will be executed. If X is 1, all three methods will be executed.

If you want only the linked method to be called, change the code into:

```
Switch(X){
case 1: doOne(); break;
case 2: doTwo(); break;
case 3: doThree(); break;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are not using `break;` after every `case` which causes the cases below to execute even if you do not want them to. For eg, this is correct :-

```
switch(int){ 
   case 1:
   break;
   case 2:
   break;
 }
```

and this will cause unexpected output though it is not wrong:-

```
switch(int){ 
   case 1:
   case 2:
 }
```

Omitting `break` will cause execution of case 2 after executing case 1.